# Using pandas dataframe function .mul in Python 3.x

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to multiply two dataframes with the `mul()` function, but it's not working.

I created two dataframes:

```
x = np.arange(0.,5.,0.2)
m = len(x)
ones  = np.ones(m)
theta = {'1':np.zeros(2)}
X = {'1':pd.Series(ones), '2':pd.Series(x)}
THETAdf = pd.DataFrame(theta)
Xdf = pd.DataFrame(X)
```

And I tried this:

```
mult = Xdf.mul(THETAdf)
print (mult)
```

The result is:

```
        1   2
0   0.0 NaN
1   0.0 NaN
2   NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN
5   NaN NaN
6   NaN NaN
7   NaN NaN
8   NaN NaN
9   NaN NaN
10  NaN NaN
11  NaN NaN
12  NaN NaN
13  NaN NaN
14  NaN NaN
15  NaN NaN
16  NaN NaN
17  NaN NaN
18  NaN NaN
19  NaN NaN
20  NaN NaN
21  NaN NaN
22  NaN NaN
23  NaN NaN
24  NaN NaN
```

Should I use another way to multiply?

Comment: Pandas aligns the DataFrames based on the column and row indices. The result is as expected since `THETAdf` only has `0` and `1` in its row index, and `1` in its column index. What is your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.dot` for matrix multiplication with DataFrame or Series objects. You can use `.values` so that it does not align on the index/columns.

```
>>> Xdf.dot(THETAdf.values).head()
   0
0  0
1  0
2  0
3  0
4  0
```